# Secure cells in a way that I can only add +1 to them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

I have a bunch of cells with numbers in them. I want them to secure them in a way that I can only add +1 to them. Now I do this manually (4 becomes 5 etc.etc.).

Assuming Google Spreadsheets doesn't have nifty up/down arrow for a cell increasing/decreasing +1 / -1, I think I'm supposed to use a script.

Something like this

```
function increment() {  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("F5").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("F5").getValue() + 1);
}
```

But if I'm using this script (creating numerous drawings (grrr) ), I'm supposed to create x of the same functions? Seems a bit dumb.

This gives me errors

```
function increment(mycell) {  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(mycell).setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(mycell).getValue() + 1);
}
```

> **Usage:** increment(F5)
>   **Error:** function increment(F5) not found.

?

Comment: How do you want to use this function? Do you want to type `=increment(F5)` into another cell? And do you want the incremented value to be returned to `F5` or another cell?

Comment: @ziganotschka to that same cell. So if I would use increment(F5) that would add 1 to cell F5. 

using increment(B4) would add 1 to cell B4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem about your approach is the recursion

Sheet formulas are by default recalculated, so should you type into a cell a formula that increments the value in another cell by `1` - once the value increases, this will trigger the formula recalculation and request the value to increase again and so on.

So you cannot implement your idea in this way

**Workaround**

- Create a function that increments the value of the current cell
- You bind this function e.g. to a button and trigger execution after you click into the desired cell and clicked on the button

Sample function:

```
function increment() {  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell().setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell().getValue() + 1);
}
```

To create a button:

- Go from the Sheets UI on `Insert->Drawing`
- Draw a shape of your choice and click on `Save and close`
- Click on the three vertical dots in the right upper corner of the drawing
- Select `Assign script`
  [image]
- Type in the name of the function (without `()`)
- Click into the cell the value of which you want to increment
- Click onto your drawing to run the script - done!

[image]